# bash asterisk escape prints \* in echo

Tags: bash, escaping

I want to print * character in echo. Current behaviour prints my script filename:

```
result="multiply $1 * $2 is = $[$1*$2]"
```

myfile.sh 2 5
prints:

```
multiply 2 myfile.sh 5 is 10
```

I've read similar problem and answers and my approaches were:

```
result="multiply $1 '*' $2 is = $[$1*$2]"
```

which gave:

```
multiply 2 '*' 5 is 10
```

So another approach was to make a variable:

```
helper="*"
result="multiply $1 "$helper" $2 is = $[$1*$2]"
```

but the result was the same:

```
multiply 2 myfile.sh 5 is 10
```

What is the problem?

Full code:

```
function multiply {
result="multiply $1 * $2 is = $[$1*$2]"
}

multiply $1 $2
echo $result
```

I tried escaping the asterisk with * but it prints:

```
multiply 2 \* 5 is 10
```

Comment: `echo "$result"`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thank you, it works. You can post the answer and I'll mark it as complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
echo $result
```

with

```
echo "$result"
```

Use `shellcheck`:

```
$ shellcheck ./myfile.sh

In ./myfile.sh line 4:
    result="multiply $1 * $2 is = $[$1*$2]"
                                  ^------^ SC2007: Use $((..)) instead of deprecated $[..]


In ./myfile.sh line 7:
multiply $1 $2
         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
multiply "$1" "$2"


In ./myfile.sh line 8:
echo $result
     ^-----^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
echo "$result"

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2007 -- Use $((..)) instead of deprecated...
```